# What is the difference between * and *.* in bower versioning for bower.json

Tags: bower, bower-install

I have seen some people use the first way while some use the second. I don't see what the particular difference is. Is there specific scenario I would want to use one or the other?

For example, in a bower.json, I use

```
"dialog": "https://gitlab.com/dialog.git#^1.*.*"
```

and it seems to get the same results when I run `bower install` as

```
"dialog": "https://gitlab.com/dialog.git#^1.*"
```